# Dynamic Navigation in React Native after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

My app has a dynamic authentication flow where the user is directed to different screens after they are authenticated. the problem is the user can be authenticated either after sign up or after login .
I'm struggling to navigate to specific screens based on whether it was an authentication with login or an authentication with signup.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"LoadingScreen"} headerMode='none'>
    {user ? (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name='OnBoarding' component={OnBoarding} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Preferences' component={Preferences} />
        <Stack.Screen name='TabNav' component={TabNav} />
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name='Signup' component={Signup} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
      </>
    )}
    <Stack.Screen name='LoadingScreen' component={LoadingScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

In this setup, after the user authenticates ,  the app always navigates to the first screen (Home in this case).

Also in react navigation docs they say :

> Don't manually navigate when conditionally rendering screens
> It's important to note that when using such a setup, you don't manually navigate to the Home screen by calling navigation.navigate('Home') or any other method. React Navigation will automatically navigate to the correct screen when isSignedIn changes - Home screen when isSignedIn becomes true, and to SignIn screen when isSignedIn becomes false. You'll get an error if you attempt to navigate manually.

However, I want the navigation to be dynamic, such as navigating to the OnBoarding screen after the signup process and to the Home screen after login.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to put any check inside `Stack.Navigator`. let's load all screen when app running and navigate on specific screen based on auth bit like `auth_token` etc.

when you navigate to `login` or `signup` screen remember the name of screen where you want to navigate once authenticated.

Now navigate that screen dynamically, here you may face navigation problem if screen are nested. so you have to look into it deeply how your `navigation flow` configured.

If it is nested then navigate accordingly.

**Example:**

For simple navigation: `navigation.navigate('screenName')`

Suppose I have a screen `StarterStack > Home > specificScreen`

For Nested Navigation:

```
navigation.navigate('StarterStack', {
            screen: 'Home',
            params: {
              screen: specificScreen,
            },
          });
```

By keeping this nested flow in mind you can adjust your navigation easily.

Hope it will help you.